# How to check order of occurring of strings using java regular expression patterns?

Tags: java, regex

I have written the following code to match an pattern and it works well returning true for matched

```
   Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile("(:(TRANSID,[0-9]*))?(:(PAYTYPE,[0-9&&[01]]{1}))?");
   Matcher matcher=pattern.matcher(":TRANSID,0:PAYTYPE,0");
   System.out.println(matcher.matches());

   Output=true
```

but the below code returns false when PAYTYPE and TRANSID exchange there positions. Please help

```
   Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile("(:(TRANSID,[0-9]*))?(:(PAYTYPE,[0-9&&[01]]{1}))?");
   Matcher matcher=pattern.matcher(":PAYTYPE,0:TRANSID,0");
   System.out.println(matcher.matches());

   Output=false
```

Please let me know the change need to be done in the pattern so that it returns true even though order changes but parameters should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
[(:(TRANSID,[0-9]*)) | (:(PAYTYPE,[0-9&&[01]]{1}))]*
```

Something like this anyway. Use the OR operator. If you need to ensure exactly two matches in either order you could try...

```
[(:(TRANSID,[0-9]*)) | (:(PAYTYPE,[0-9&&[01]]{1}))] [(:(TRANSID,[0-9]*)) | (:(PAYTYPE,[0-9&&[01]]{1}))]
```

Comment: @Hari not really his job to test it, if it is wrong, just downvote.

Comment: @ Marcelo, I am sorry for that.But anyways, the solution did'nt help me since there are 14 strings that i need to check for the combination and compare.

Comment: I don't have a chance to test it. It was a suggestion of the type of thing that might work (or-ing two blocks). You need to play with it to fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 14 different sub-patterns patterns that may occur in any order, but must occur a certain number of times (for each sub-pattern), this is beyond what you can sensibly do with Regexes ... or even with a context free grammar.

My advice would design a Regex that matches an arbitrary sequence of any of the sub-patterns, and then collate / count them using a `Map`.